# updating WCF service reference - could not load Entity Framework

Tags: .net, wcf, service, service-reference

I added two additional methods to my WCF service and now I want to update my service reference but it continues to error for some reason that I can't seem to figure out. It throws a warning on trying to load `EntityFramework version 4.4.0.0`.

I don't actually use `EntityFramework` and I have removed all references of it from my project. I ran `PM> Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force` as well as removed any remnants of `EntityFramework` that were in the `web.Config`. Also the reference that was removed was version 5.0.0.0.

The project shouldn't even need the reference as well as why is it looking to load version 4.4?

The project builds fine as well as the service, but it will not generate the updated reference.

edit:

Here's the errors.

```
Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'DeployService'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details.

Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IDeployService']
```

Also, I only get this error if I have it set to reuse types in references assemblies

**UPDATE:**

I'm leaving this ticket unresolved in case someone can provide an actual solution to the issue.

I was able to get the update to work on my project by using "Reuse types in a specific reference assemblies" instead of "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies". Doing this I opted to not reuse any of the Microsoft assemblies and instead just selected the assemblies I needed to remain the same, namely references to my own entities. Something about reusing the Microsoft assemblies, in this case entity framework, was causing issues.

[image]

Comment: How about you copy that error text and paste it into an [edit]?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?  I'm seeing this same issue adding a new Service Reference.

Comment: @Adam47 I've updated my question. I'll still leave the question unresolved.